# Web API object sharing

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi

I have a problem with my objects.

I used to have two objects that were mostly the same but one had some extra fields, so I merged them into one.

Now the problem I am having is that when I do my web api documentation using swagger it is displaying the entire object, but for some calls I only want to use part of the object.

My question is, if I have one object with the base values, is it possible to make another object use the base object as a starting point/reference from which I can add the extra values I require ?

Comment: Yes - this is called inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your question is in OOP, inheritance

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

SecondClass will have both Property1 and Property2